# Printing multiple pages from an ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, printing, arraylist

First let me start off with I am not a vb.net developer. In fact I have never been trained in the art of VB. That being said I am working on a very simple application that takes a csv file and parses a single column to an array list. Now i need to take that array list and print a individual page (Without preview) of each item on the array list. So each item on the array list will have its own page.

Heres what i have so far. Im sure Im way off seeing as I cant figure out how to turn this into multi-pages.

```
    Private Sub Print()
    Dim PrintPreviewSelected As Boolean = False
    'Set the doc to print
    Dim pDoc As New PrintDocument
    pDoc.PrintController = New StandardPrintController   'turns off the printing page x of y dialog
    Try
        Using sr As New StreamReader(file)
            defPrinter = sr.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    Catch e As Exception
    End Try
    If defPrinter = "" Then
        If Me.PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            pDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = Me.PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
        End If
    Else
        pDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = defPrinter
    End If
    pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    pDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Margins(40, 10, 10, 10)
    pDoc.OriginAtMargins = True
    AddHandler pDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintSett
    If PrintPreviewSelected Then
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = pDoc
        PrintPreviewDialog1.UseAntiAlias = True
        PrintPreviewDialog1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Else
        If txtFile.Text <> "" Then
            pDoc.Print()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a file first", "Select a file.")
        End If
    End If
    RemoveHandler pDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintSett
End Sub

Private Sub PrintSett(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim fnt10 As Font = New Font("Courier New", 34, FontStyle.Regular)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("", fnt10, Brushes.Black, 318, 412)
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated! I know i havent laid any of the foundation for you guys to work off of but frankly Im strait up lost. Thanks guys!

Comment: you should do it line by line in `sub printsett` .. it will increment the Y location and when got bigger than paper height you should do `e.hasmorepages=true` ...

Comment: Any way you can elaborate. Ive tried running a for each loop inside the print however it causes a print loop.

Answer (score 2):

Following matzone's suggestion I was able to figure it out.

```
Dim PageNumber As Integer = 1
Dim morePage As String

Private Sub PrintSett(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim ReportFont As New Font("Arial", 45, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim VerticalPrintLocationSingle As Single = 412
    Dim HorizontalPrintLocationSingle As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
    Dim TextString As String
    Dim sngCenterPage As Single

    If customerList.Count > (PageNumber) Then

        If customerList.Item(PageNumber) IsNot "" Then
            TextString = customerList.Item(PageNumber)
            Console.WriteLine(customerList.Item(PageNumber))
            sngCenterPage = Convert.ToSingle(e.PageBounds.Width / 2 - e.Graphics.MeasureString(customerList.Item(PageNumber), ReportFont).Width / 2)
            PageNumber += 1
            morePage = True
        End If

    Else
        morePage = False
        customerList.Clear()
    End If

    e.Graphics.DrawString(TextString, ReportFont, Brushes.Black, sngCenterPage, VerticalPrintLocationSingle)
    e.HasMorePages = morePage
End Sub
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Haha thanks! I kinda skipped right over the whole "Hello World" tutorial.